Wso2 4.4.0 Can not APIM manager Advanced UI Customization
I am having problem doing Advanced UI Customization I have followed the steps to edit the look and feel of the devportal. I copied the wso2 webapps file to another folder and ran npm install, then npm run bootstrap, then went to the devportal folder and ran npm run build dev. But I tried to overwrite a React file in the folder where I copied webapps. Then I rebuilt and copied the dist file and there was an overwritten file of React. But I copied the dist file in the webapps folder (coppy) to the webapps folder (root) and also the index.jsp file, but then I ran the api-manager.bat --run command again and didn't see any change in the interface. . Please help me know where I went wrong. I am using wso2 4.4.0. I have read the document and followed it but I don't see any change. Can you help me please. I followed these steps: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/advanced-ui-customization/
Can someone tell me which step I did wrong. I have made Make the UI related changes in the respective folder based on the WSO2 API-M Console.
If you need to rewrite the UI completely, you can make changes in the following directory.
Developer Portal - devportal/source
Publisher Portal - publisher/source
If you want to override a specific React component or a file from the source/src/ directory, you need to make the changes in the following directory by only copying the desired file/files.
Developer Portal - devportal/override/src
Publisher Portal - publisher/override/src in the webapps folder (the folder I copied to see if that is correct) or must I directly modify the fe code on the root webapps folder of wso2
